# Is there any way for Mac dashboard widget to reload himself

Tags: javascript, macos, widget, dashboard, mac-dashboard-widget

My dashboard widget has automatic update system, but after every update user should press ⌘R for changes to take a place. I want to do it automaticaly, without any user actions.

Is there any widget method to reload it?

Common methods doesn't works: I've tried to call window.location.reload(), history.go(0) & window.location.href=window.location.href — every method throws an error.